Repair Grub/UEFI boot settings with a root filesystem on a logical volume
So I recently set up a  new virtual private server to host a couple of things using YunoHost. It runs Debian 12. During inital setup, I declared both the main drive and a second drive (Local Block Storage) to be logical volumes in the same group so that instead of two 500GB drives I now had a single 1TB one.
Initial bootup was no problem, but ever since then, it keeps failing. The server just doesn't boot into Debian, but rather into Grub2, which unhelpfully finds the efi partition, declares all actual physical volumes to be unreadable and just won't

ls (lvm/LogVol)

for whatever reason.
However, when I virtually insert a GParted live usb, I have the option to not boot into the live usb image, but to choose an option called "UEFI firmware settings". When I select that and then "Debian" from the list of options, I boot into my system just fine.
What gives?
Output of grub-install, grub-update and efibootmgr:
me@killefitt:~$ sudo grub-install
[sudo] password for me:
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

me@killefitt:~$ sudo update-grub

Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-28-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-28-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-18-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

me@killefitt:~$ sudo efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 3 seconds
BootOrder: 0009,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0000,0008,000A
Boot0000* UiApp
Boot0001* UEFI QEMU DVD-ROM QM00001
Boot0002* UEFI Misc Device
Boot0003* UEFI PXEv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0004* UEFI PXEv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980) 2
Boot0005* UEFI PXEv6 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0006* UEFI HTTPv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0007* UEFI HTTPv6 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0008* EFI Internal Shell
Boot0009* debian
Boot000A* UEFI Misc Device 2

me@killefitt:~$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0009,0001

BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 3 seconds
BootOrder: 0009,0001
Boot0000* UiApp
Boot0001* UEFI QEMU DVD-ROM QM00001
Boot0002* UEFI Misc Device
Boot0003* UEFI PXEv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0004* UEFI PXEv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980) 2
Boot0005* UEFI PXEv6 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0006* UEFI HTTPv4 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0007* UEFI HTTPv6 (MAC:4A5A629B3980)
Boot0008* EFI Internal Shell
Boot0009* debian
Boot000A* UEFI Misc Device 2


me@killefitt:~$ sudo journalctl -b | grep EFI

Dec 12 21:44:04 killefitt.eu kernel: efi: EFI v2.70 by EDK II
Dec 12 21:44:04 killefitt.eu kernel: fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device

